# Disable setting attribute in FactoryBot

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, factory-bot

I have an ActiveRecord model with an `active` field. I have some validations which will certainly fail if `active = true` upon creation. I'm setting `active` to false in my factory by default, but I'd like to go the extra mile and disable the possibility of changing it, preferably with a meaningful error message. How can I do that?

A valid use case would look like this:

```
my_model = create(:my_model) # my_model.active == false
# do some other setup
my_model.update!(active: true)
```

What I want to achieve is this

```
create(:my_model, active: true)
# => raise FactoryOptionsNotAllowed: cannot be active upon creation
```

Unfortunately, `after(:build)` is not bulletproof as [it runs after associations are saved](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/issues/649). So when an error happens during saving the associaition, it will not reach `after(:build)`.

Comment: Do you want to prevent the attribute changing system wide or just in your specs?

Comment: Just in the factory. Added an example to clarify.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `after(:build)` in your factory:

```
factory :my_model do
  active { true }

  after(:build) do |model|
    unless model.active
      raise FactoryBot::InvalidFactoryError, 'active cannot be false'
    end
  end
end
```

You may want to define your own exception type rather than using the FactoryBot `InvalidFactoryError`.

Comment: This is cool, thanks. Unfortunately in my case, the error comes earlier from an `association` and it fails before `after(:build)` so I would need an earlier intervention if one exists. This issue explains how associations are saved before the `after(:build)` hook of the parent: https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/issues/649